# how to make a new line on tex file for FileOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, newline, fileoutputstream

How can I create a new line for each loop? My program keeps on displaying everything in a single line... or how can I set a diff class to write data from arrays

```
static void writetofile(studentClass[] students)
   {
       try(DataOutputStream str= new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("new.txt"))  )
     {

      for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++)
      {
         str.writeBytes(students[i].getStudentFname()+", ");
         str.writeBytes(students[i].getStudentLname()+" ");
         str.writeBytes(Integer.toString(students[i].getTestSore()));
         str.writeBytes(" ");
         str.writeChar(students[i].getGrade());
         str.writeBytes("\n");


      }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println("Error");
     }
   }
```

Comment: Are you viewing `new.txt` in notepad? If so, you'd need to use `"\r\n"` as the line separator.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question but I'd like to say it's a bad practice having a method with names like `getStudentFName`. Assuming it belongs to the class `Student` you would be repeating the word "student" twice (`student.getStudentFName`). There's no need to be redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `DataOutputStream` to write a *text* file. Use a `Writer`.

Javadoc of [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) says:

> A `DataOutputStream` lets an application write **primitive Java data types** to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then use a [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read the data back in.

It is for writing Java primitive types in a portable *binary* format. Not for writing a *text* file.

A [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) however:

> Abstract class for writing to **character** streams.

To help print newlines, use a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream.

Then the [`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) method will write the correct line terminator for you.

So, your code should be:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("new.txt")))
{
    for (Student student : students)
    {
        out.println(student.getStudentFname() + ", " +
                    student.getStudentLname() + " " +
                    student.getTestSore() + " " +
                    student.getGrade());
    }
}
```

You can so use the formatting version, [`printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("new.txt"))) {
    for (Student student : students)
        out.printf("%s, %s %d %c%n",
                   student.getStudentFname(),
                   student.getStudentLname(),
                   student.getTestSore(),
                   student.getGrade());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are using the wrong line separator for however you are trying to view the file: Windows uses `\r\n` as the line separator, *nix uses `\n` etc.

If you are using a text editor/viewier worth its salt to view the file (i.e. not notepad), this shouldn't matter, though - it should detect the line separator.

---

You might find it easier to use a `java.util.Formatter` instead of a `DataOutputStream` (and an enhanced for loop):

```
try (Formatter fmt = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream(...)) {
  for (studentClass student : students) {
    fmt.format("%s, %s %d %s%n",
        student.getStudentFname(),
        student.getStudentLname(),
        student.getTestSore(),
        student.getGrade());
  }      
}
```

Note that this uses `%n`, the platform-specific line separator for the platform on which the code is run. If you want to specify a particular line separator, you can use `\n` (or `\r\n`, or whatever) instead.

Comment: I used the original code and works good if you open it in notepad++ but when I open it in notepad as you said, it writes everything side by side. I changed the str.writeBytes("\n"); as str.writeBytes("\r\n"); it works fine in both editors.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```